# How to search inside a JSON string with a SQL query when not every row that is being searched in contains JSON?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database

I've got a table that contains a column (`rated_by`) with some id's in json format. Example: `["59"]`

I would like to search for a specific number in all `rated_by` columns of the entire table.
I've done this  before in the same table for another column that also contain id's in the same format as above with the following query (for the column `producten)`:

```
SELECT * FROM review WHERE JSON_SEARCH(producten,"one", "26") IS NOT NULL ORDER BY useful DESC
```

This works fine and this is because every row of `producten` is filled with json, not a single one is empty, but for `rated_by` some rows can be empty.

Using the exact same query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM review WHERE JSON_SEARCH(rated_by,"one", "59") IS NOT NULL
```

I get: `Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_search: "The document is empty." at position 0.`

I tested it by emptying one row of `producten` and trying the working query again, it stopped working.

So the problem is my query stops working when one row of `rated_by` does not contain json or is empty.

Why is that? I thought using `IS NOT NULL` would tackle this.

I am using MYSQL.

Comment: @Akina  My bad, I copy pasted it wrong from my code. I put the correct query in my post now.

Comment: The issue is caused by [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) requiring a document or will emit an error when the argument is not a valid document. Ensure the value is an actual document before calling `JSON_SEARCH`. `WHERE JSON_VALID(rated_by) AND JSON_SEARCH(rated_by,"one", "59") IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using `JSON_VALID` (first check if the row contains valid json, only if it does, retrieve data) as commented above.

Working query:

```
SELECT * FROM review WHERE JSON_VALID(rated_by) AND review_id = "10" AND JSON_SEARCH(rated_by,"one", "59") IS NOT NULL
```